# task.isSuccessfull() always false

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this is the code it all works until the if(task.isSuccessfull()) and them it does not enter the if How to fix it?thanks

```
private void Login()
{
    String email = etEmail_login.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = etPass_login.getText().toString().trim();
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "connecting" ,"please wait...",true);
    pd.show();
    DBref.Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Boolean x = task.isSuccessful();
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getBaseContext(), Wellcome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you always getting x = true or false?

Comment: I am always getting x=false(the x is just for debug purposes)

Comment: Can we see your more code related to Firebase (Auth)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.